# Modify pdfTeX compiled PDF metadata to have a different file save name

Tags: pdftex, pdf, resume, metadata, workflow

I am currently running a GitHub workflow to compile `main.tex` into `resume.pdf` which is deployed to an endpoint on a GitHub Pages site (website.com/resume.pdf). When I hit Ctrl + S on this page, it will automatically input `resume` as the file name. I wondered whether it was possible to alter the metadata to have a hidden file name such as `Last_First.pdf` that pops up on a save prompt while conserving the endpoint.

Comment: I think the question currently lacks details/clearness, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228 for example.